# Man-in-the-middle attack only affects TLS certs with unqualified subject names?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

A question came up when I was discussing that Man in the middle attacks can occur when certificates have subject names are not qualified (e.g. "localhost"). I was then told that MitM only happens when it's a TLS certificate with an unqualified subject name.

My question is, wouldn't MitM also affect other types of certificates that have unqualified names? (I'm assuming the person I'm speaking to is referring to encryption certs, digital signature or code signing certificates, etc. when he implies MitM only affects TLS certs)

For example, if I have a certificate that is both self-signed and also uses an unqualified name, can't I also create self-signed certificate with the same unqualified SubjectName and then gain access? I read somewhere that eavesdropping isn't considered MitM. Maybe that's the distinction? Perhaps the other person is using the more traditional definition of MitM and I am thinking more of an eavesdropping attack risk with self-signed and unqualified names?

I could gain access to systems that use certificate authentication with a self-signed cert with unqualified names by simply creating my own to match what's being used for entry, right? But that isn't really considered MitM anymore in the traditional sense but perhaps unauthorized access or information disclosure, right?

Comment: Wouldn't the risk be with self-signed certificates and certs that are not "fully qualified"? If I create a self-signed cert to get my own identical copy of a cert that's called just CN=Exchange, wouldn't this pose a risk?

Comment: Please don't invent new terms and then ask questions using those terms. You mean a certificate with an unqualified domain name, ***not*** an unqualified certificate.

Comment: schroeder you sound really passive aggressive and it doesn't land well with me. Ever heard of short-hand or referring to something in a conversational way? If you need clarification to see what I mean then ask without sounding like you're taking out whatever frustrations you have on me.  A simple, "Do you mean using unqualified names?" instead of your passive aggressive tone would work. If the StackExchange community is like you then I want nothing of it.I actually used to moderate for a popular message board; I remember how angsty people like you get and don't miss it. Somethings never change

Comment: People's ability to determine tone from the written word is very poor. I did in fact ask for clarification. You answered, and what resulted from the answer was that you *rephrased* what was in the links you referenced. As for "conversational way", that's not what happened. Your rephrasing caused so much confusion that the only people who responded to your question didn't know what you were talking about. This confusion is on you. Don't make this into my problem.

Comment: And given the response of the community to your other question, I think you need to consider that your imprecision in your questions about highly technical subjects is causing a distraction to the ability for others to answer you. You need to take this constructive criticism on board and reconsider how you write. We are not mind readers, and you are talking to industry experts in this field. You need to be able to align with the field.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "fully qualified" certificate. That term simply does not exist in the vocabulary surrounding certificates and PKI. I *believe* you mean "trusted" certificates - which would be a certificate, which has been signed by a trusted certificate authority (or which can establish a chain of trust to such an authority).

The opposite of that would be a self-signed certificate, or a certificate signed by an untrusted root certificate.

> I was then told that MitM only happens when it's an unqualified TLS cert.

That is not exactly true. Man-in-the-Middle attacks can occur regardless of whether a certificate is trusted by the host or not. Where it differs is in what the client sees during a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

The attacker will not have a certificate, which is signed by trusted certificate authority, which relates to the server in question. As a result, the connection will *always* display an error, that the certificate in question is untrusted.

If the original certificate is self-signed as well and has not been manually added to the trust store (more on this later), then users will *expect* to get a certificate error, whenever they connect to the application. Thus, they will not realize that their connection is being highjacked.

If the original certificate is signed by a trusted certificate authority (either public or internal), then users would be faced with an unfamiliar error message. This *should* cause users to suspect that something is wrong and cause them to not blindly click on "Click here to connect anyways and lose all your data to hackers".

The important distinction is not that a trusted certificate will *prevent* a Man-in-the-Middle attack, but that it will make it *detectable*. And depending on the configuration of the client, make it impossible for the user to connect to an untrusted endpoint.

---

> can't I also create an unqualified and self-signed certificate with the same certificate SubjectName and then gain access?

I *presume* that this relates to client certificates, not server certificates. And depending on the setup of the server, this *may* be possible. However, if it is possible, then the server has a critical configuration vulnerability.

So first, allow me to explain how it *should* work. First, a certificate authority is created and the certificate of that authority is copied to the server. Second, legitimate users are given certificates, signed by that certificate authority. Finally, the server is configured to only give access to users, which have certificates signed by that specific certificate authority.

An attacker could try to create a self-signed certificate and "impersonate" the certificate authority, by using - as you said - the same data the certificate authority uses (same name, etc.). However, the private key of the certificate authority is unknown to the attacker, so they cannot create an identical copy. If the attacker would now attempt to issue a certificate for themselves using their bogus certificate authority, the validation of that certificate on the server would fail, as the public key mismatches.

This is how it *should* be, and how it likely is in the vast majority of scenarios. However, there are systems, which use client certificates completely wrong. They merely check for the fields in the certificate, and not for the signatures. In this case, it becomes trivial to forge a certificate, which impersonates arbitrary users. And while that may seem like a contrived example, I have seen this during penetration tests and red teaming assessments in multiple companies. Unfortunately, the people, who build these systems, are often not very familiar with cryptography and so tend to use cryptographic tools wrong.

> Is this considered Man-in-the-Middle?

No, it's not. You are not intercepting an existing connection and act as a "Man-in-the-Middle" between client and server. Rather, you are forging an "access token" in the broadest sense and use it to gain unauthorized access.

I would consider such an attack to be an "authentication bypass".

---

As I mentioned before, self-signed certificates *can* be secure, *if* they are explicitly trusted on an endpoint. So for example, I could create a self-signed certificate for a server called `mediaserver.local` and explicitly add that certificate to the trust store of my computer.

This certificate would then indeed be trusted and I would not receive an error message, if I attempted to connect to this server. In the eyes of my computer, the certificate is issued by a trusted party.

---

#### Regarding non-FQDNs

This depends how your client is set up. For example, a DNS server can interpret a query to `exchange` as meaning `exchange.company.local`. In such a case, a certificate merely for `exchange` would be valid. In many cases, if such a behavior is desired, it makes sense to set `exchange.company.local` as the common name, and `exchange` as a subject alternative name (SAN).

This does not fundamentally change anything regarding the security of the certificate. Even if an attacker could cause the local DNS to resolve `exchange` to a machine controlled by the attacker, the attacker still would not be able to create a certificate, which would be trusted by the client.

In short: Using non-fully qualified domain names does not make the process less secure.

---

#### To summarize

- There is no such thing as a "qualified" or "unqualified" certificate.
- A certificate can either be "trusted" or "untrusted".
- Man-in-the-Middle attacks can be performed regardless of whether a certificate is originally trusted.
- Trust exists to be able to *detect* such attacks.
- A server must verify the *signature* of a certificate, not just the contents of the fields.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is where I'm referring to the term qualified/unqualified:

https://www.secureworks.com/blog/certificate-authorities-for-ssl-tls-crypto-weak-link

https://threatpost.com/problem-issuing-certs-unqualified-names-040611/75112

https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2011/04/unqualified-names-ssl-observatory

What I am referring to is not specific to a trusted certificate by a CA, but rather having a certificate that has a SubjectName of just CN=Exchange

I would prefer to see certificates that are "fully qualified" such as CN=Exchange.domain.net

Comment: @q933a I updated the answer to include non-FQDNs. In short: It doesn't change anything. A trusted cert will still be trusted, an untrusted cert will still be untrusted. An attacker does not gain any advantage.

Comment: I don't think you're following my statement fully. An attacker could gain an advantage with "authentication bypass" if all they need to do is create a self-signed certificate with the same SubjectName right? That's a danger with self-signed certificates, right? Not referring to certs that were signed by a CA. My original question asked about this risk specific to self-signed certificates. I wouldn't really refer to a self-signed certificate as truly trusted. Wouldn't this be a risk??

Comment: @q933a You cannot use self-signed certificates for client authentication. They **must** be signed by a Certificate Authority. A client certificate inherits its trust by being signed by a CA. If there is no CA, then how would a server decide if a certificate is trusted or not?